# Creating EKS cluster by using Java application

Tags: java, amazon-eks, aws-sdk-java-2.0

everyone I am new to AWS SDK. I am trying to create an EKS cluster from my java application.

I have used this `eksctl create cluster` command to create a cluster and I have also done this by using cluster templates.

I have tried to use AWS SDK to create clusters but that didn't work and have no idea how to go with it.
If anyone of you has a good sample code or explanation of using AWS SDK for creating a cluster using **cluster template** or anything which can help me to reach there would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**here i provide you a sample of Java code. i wish its serve your purpose on eks cluster creation:**

```
    String accessKey = "your_aws_access_key";
    String secretKey = "your_aws_secret_key";

    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials (accessKey, secretKey);
    ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration ();
    clientConfig.setProtocol (Protocol.HTTPS);
    clientConfig.setMaxErrorRetry (DEFAULT_MAX_ERROR_RETRY);
    clientConfig.setRetryPolicy (new RetryPolicy (PredefinedRetryPolicies.DEFAULT_RETRY_CONDITION,
            DEFAULT_BACKOFF_STRATEGY, DEFAULT_MAX_ERROR_RETRY, false));

    AmazonEKS amazonEKS = AmazonEKSClientBuilder.standard ()
            .withClientConfiguration (clientConfig)
            .withCredentials (new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider (credentials))
            .withRegion ("us-east-1") //replace your region name
            .build ();
    CreateClusterResult eksCluster = amazonEKS.createCluster (
            new CreateClusterRequest ().withName ("cluster-name") //with other param
    );
```

Comment: Thanks mate!!
Can you please share the dependency you are using for this?

Comment: upper exapme is suing Java V1 Aws SDK here,
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.239</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: But If you famailer with Java 8+, you can use also Java v2 sdk.
        
<dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.257</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
 </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-sdk-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.257</version>
</dependency>